# How do you connect scene builder to your main class?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to connect scene builder to my main class but this error message is displayed in the compiler

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
```

How would you go about doing this the correct way?
What am I doing wrong?

I'm VERY new to java so anything helps!

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Main {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button bout0;

    @FXML
    private Button boutadd;

    @FXML
    private Button boutclear;

    @FXML
    private Button boutdec;

    @FXML
    private Button boutdivi;

    @FXML
    private Button boutegale;

    @FXML
    private Button boutmpty;

    @FXML
    private Button boutpoum;

    @FXML
    private Button boutpourc;

    @FXML
    private Button boutsous;


    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert bout0 != null : "fx:id=\"bout0\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutadd != null : "fx:id=\"boutadd\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutclear != null : "fx:id=\"boutclear\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutdec != null : "fx:id=\"boutdec\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutdivi != null : "fx:id=\"boutdivi\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutegale != null : "fx:id=\"boutegale\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutmpty != null : "fx:id=\"boutmpty\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutpoum != null : "fx:id=\"boutpoum\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutpourc != null : "fx:id=\"boutpourc\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
        assert boutsous != null : "fx:id=\"boutsous\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Jdmd.fxml'.";
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's a controller class (judging by the `@FXML` annotations, and the `initialize()` method). The field for the controller class is in the "controller" expandable pane, which is in the bottom left of Scene Builder. The error though (which is not in the compiler... where are you actually getting that error?) seems to be trying to *execute* this class (i.e. it is looking for either a class with a `main()` method, or an `Application` subclass). It looks like you have confused the two ideas (controller class and application class).

Comment: You don't need to say you're new, or apologize or say pleasant things. Everyone does it and it gets old quickly. We are here to just solve the problem. Also, you didn't indent your code far enough and braces fell out of the code block.  I usually bring my code up in an editor and indent the block and then cut/paste it here to avoid that problem.  You might want to edit your code to fix the formatting.  If you properly format the code here in generall you're often more likely to get a quicker response.

Comment: Download Netbeans and install it. Click "File" then "New Project". Find the JavaFX folder and click it. Next under "Projects:" click "JavaFx FXML Application" Hit the Next> button. Name your project and hit the Finish button. From this point there are two ways to open FXML files in Scenebuilder. One way is by installing Scenebuilder and Letting Netbeans know through options. The other is by using Scenebuilder jar to open the file.